# how to add multi captcha in same page and check both checkbox its fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, captcha

I have two forms on a single page, one of them is a login form and the other is a register form (two tabs) and I want to check the the captchas, but when I click the check captcha from register form I can't login.

The login form:

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="loginUserTab" class="tab-pane fade">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group login-width-100">
      <label for="id_number" class="m-rtl-label"><span class="requiredMark">*</span>passport number:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pNo" name="pNo" data-validetta="required,minLength[10],maxLength[10]" lang="fa" style="text-align: left;">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group login-width-100">
      <label for="mNumber" class="m-rtl-label"><span class="requiredMark"></span>  telephone :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tNumber" name="tNumber" data-validetta="required,minLength[11],maxLength[11]" lang="fa" style="text-align: left;">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="float:right;padding-right: 20px;">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="...."></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group login-width-100">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary colorGreenBTN">login</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### JS:

```js
var v = grecaptcha.getResponse();
if (v.length == 0) {
  alert("fill the form");
  return;
} else if (!$("#Terms").prop("checked")) {
  alert("check the rules");
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the script tags `<script></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Way to validate as much g-captcha validate

Hope you have included `api.js` before `</head>` tag as per below

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit"></script>
```

Your HTML Code looks like below

```
<div class="g-recaptcha-contact" data-sitekey="Your Site Key" id="RecaptchaField2"></div>
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha" name="ct_hiddenRecaptcha" id="ct_hiddenRecaptcha">

<div class="g-recaptcha-quote" data-sitekey="Your Site Key" id="RecaptchaField1"></div>
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenRecaptcha" name="qt_hiddenRecaptcha" id="qt_hiddenRecaptcha">
```

**After you add this code in footer with  tag**

```
var CaptchaCallback = function() {
    var widgetId1;
    var widgetId2;
    widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField1', {'sitekey' : 'Your Site Key', 'callback' : correctCaptcha_quote});
    widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render('RecaptchaField2', {'sitekey' : 'Your Site Key', 'callback' : correctCaptcha_contact});
};
var correctCaptcha_quote = function(response) {
    $("#qt_hiddenRecaptcha").val(response);
};
var correctCaptcha_contact = function(response) {
    $("#ct_hiddenRecaptcha").val(response);
};
```

**And Last easy step for developer add Jquery Validation as per below**

```
$("#form_id").validate({
    ignore: [],
    rules: {
        ct_hiddenRecaptcha: { required: true, },
        qt_hiddenRecaptcha: { required: true, },
    },
});
```

If you have same class for both the forms, you can use it to validate above.